# sort decimal numbers from csv file in bash

Tags: bash, sorting

I have this csv file:

```
A,0,10
B,20,.66
C,2,.72
D,1,.42
E,0,0
F,0,0
G,2,.56
```

I need to sort that based on the 3rd column so it will look like this:

```
A,0,10
C,2,.72
B,20,.66
G,2,.56
D,1,.42
E,0,0
F,0,0
```

I have tried with:

```
sort -t, -V -k3 input.txt
```

but its not giving the correct result. Any suggestion?

Based on below answer I have tried:

```
sort -t, -nr -k3 input.txt
```

but that gives:

```
C,2,.72
B,20,.66
G,2,.56
D,1,.42
A,0,10
F,0,0
E,0,0
```

which is not the expected result as I provided above.

Based on this:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/292087/how-do-i-get-bc-to-start-decimal-fractions-with-a-leading-zero

I am now prefixing with 0 and that gives the correct result when sorting.

Comment: That is strange I got the exact output that you suggested

Comment: Your locale might've messed the sorting, trying using `LC_ALL=C sort ...`.

Comment: u123, Have you checked that your original file is unchanged from the original to be sorted state with your trial of the suggested answer, numeric sort. Should not make any difference, but just check answer with a correct original file afresh.  Otherwise, try PesaThe in their comment above. If that works, let us know. Interested.

Comment: Where do I put: LC_ALL=C sort ... ?

Comment: @u123 just before executing sort in the terminal before sort use LC_ALL=C

Comment: OK, but that does not explain why it worked for me, without need to add a leading 0.  Did you get the chance to try LC_ALL=C on one command line, then the solution by @Inder, with an original as you first proposed file and get the right outcome you seek?

Answer (score 4):

using numeric sort will do the trick:

```
sort -t, -nr -k3 1.txt
```

You are using Version sort which is why you are getting the ouput that you are getting.

Comment: In OSX, copy and paste original text for sort to Text Edit. Convert to plain text. Change .txt to .csv. Then in Bash run this answer, I get the correct desired result. That which OP seeks.

Comment: @Cam_Aust Thank you for the information, I got the result OP wants with .txt as well , are you getting a different result when you are doing it with .txt ???

Comment: Confirm yes. Same result when a .txt file.

Comment: Running: GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)  OSX 10.11.6.

Comment: @Cam_Aust Most like I think OP is facing the issue that PesaThe suggested.